# How to wait for all dynamic number of forks to complete with redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to use redux saga to query a number of rest endpoints to get a human readable name associated with each discovered network, to fill a dropdown list with selectable networks.

I'm having trouble doing this, my forking is not working.  I keep getting the error message:

```
TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(..) is not a function(...)
```

Every example using all() I've found online use call and know ahead of time every request being made.  However, judging from the API I tried something like this:

```
const pendingQueries = [];
for(networkId in discoveredNetworks) {
  pendingQueries.push(fork(getApplicationName, networkId);
}

const queryResults = yield all(pendingQueries);
```

This failed.  I've tried a number of other permutations since.  From testing I'm able to verify that I can do this:

```
const results = [];

for(networkId in discoveredNetworks) {
   results.push(yield fork(getApplicationName, networkId));
 }
```

and if There is a long enough delay the method will run and complete, though this approach obviously doesn't gaurentee that the forked methods will complete before I use result as I want.  Still it seems to confirm the problem is in my use of all.

What is wrong with my all command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by giving up on the all() method, which I never got to work as advertised but wasn't really the right method for the job.

For forks I should have been using join() instead.  so something along the lines of this:

```
const pendingQueries = [];
for(networkId in discoveredNetworks) {
  pendingQueries.push(yield fork(getApplicationName, networkId);
}

const results = yield join(...pendingQueries);

results.forEach((result) => {
  // my logic for handling the response and generating action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don’t you wrap each request in a promise and call them like so:

```
var promises = []
for(networkId in discoveredNetworks) {
   promises.push(new Promise((res, rej) => {
        // code from getApplicationName goes here 
        // call res(result) on success and rej(error) on failure 
   }));
}
const results = yield call(Promise.all(promises))
```

Comment: This almost works, but it means that the promises aren't canceled if the parent generator is.  This is a problem for my implementation as I don't want to continue making requsts to a bandwidth-limited system if the user no longer needs the data (ie, user changed to another view).

Comment: Okay, in that case take a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cancel